# Plotting an axis on a scatter3 figure

Tags: matlab

Hello I would like to display an axis centered on [0,0,0] of a scatter 3 plot.

Is there a way to do this using the line function?

http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html

Not quite sure how to interpret it. Would greatly appreciate a hand.

Comment: It is a shame really, it seems both 2D and [3D coordinate axis](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-coordinatesystem3d.html) is already implemented in mupad, but what I can see, not in matlab.

Comment: @Trippy: Removing your question you are violating the idea of stackoverflow. The idea is to have those questions available for further readers to help people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the axes try adding:

```
hold on;
line(xlim,[0,0],[0,0]);
line([0,0],ylim,[0,0]);
line([0,0],[0,0],zlim);
```

After your scatter plot.

**EDIT:**

If you want to place the axes with origin at another point, you can do as follows:

```
hold on;
line(xlim,[origin(2),origin(2)],[origin(3),origin(3)]);
line([origin(1),origin(1)],ylim,[origin(3),origin(3)]);
line([origin(1),origin(1)],[origin(2),origin(2)],zlim);
```

Where `origin` is the point where you want the axes to meet.